# Android Kotlin Testing: Wanted but not invoked, Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

Just want to ask about my Unit.Testing error, so i have Unit.Testing like below and when i run this test i get error **Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.** the point is i want to test that my requested data from the api is successfully displayed.

in the gradle, i already implement the

- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0
- org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.21.0

My UnitTesting is like this, i used mockito to do the test:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.TestContextProvider
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.api.ApiRepository
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.api.TheSportDBApi
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.model.MatchItem
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.model.MatchItemResponse
import com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.view.MatchView
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Before
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class MatchPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var matchView: MatchView

    @Mock
    private lateinit var gson: Gson

    @Mock
    private lateinit var apiRepository: ApiRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var theSportDBApi: TheSportDBApi

    private lateinit var presenter: MatchPresenter

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        presenter = MatchPresenter(matchView,apiRepository, gson, TestContextProvider())
    }


    @Test
    fun testGetMatchList() {
        val match: MutableList<MatchItem> = mutableListOf()
        val response = MatchItemResponse(match)
        val league = "4328"

        `when`(gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                .doRequest(theSportDBApi.getMatch(league))
                ,MatchItemResponse::class.java)).thenReturn(response)

        presenter.getMatchList(league)

        verify(matchView).showMatchList(match)
    }
}
```

The Error Detail is Like Below:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
matchView.showMatchList([]);
-> at com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.presenter.MatchPresenterTest.testGetMatchList(MatchPresenterTest.kt:52)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
matchView.showMatchList([]);
-> at com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.presenter.MatchPresenterTest.testGetMatchList(MatchPresenterTest.kt:52)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.panritech.fuad.footballmatchapp.presenter.MatchPresenterTest.testGetMatchList(MatchPresenterTest.kt:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Here is my Presenter

```
class MatchPresenter(private val matchView: MatchView,
                     private val apiRepository: ApiRepository,
                     private val gson: Gson,
                     private val context: CoroutineContextProvider = CoroutineContextProvider()) {
    fun getMatchList(league: String?) {

        async(context.main){
            val data = bg {
                gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                        .doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getMatch(league))
                        , MatchItemResponse::class.java
                )
            }
            matchView.showMatchList(data.await().events)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need more detail about the code, you can see it in my github
[link](https://github.com/fadhil1106/FootballMatchApp/tree/Submission3_UseDatabase)

Comment: you are using `async ` so the coroutine won't be called before the test finishes. I should say that I use only RxJava for now so I haven't used coroutines

Comment: quickly googling it I found that you should use `runBlocking` in your test when you call `presenter.getMatchList(league)`

Comment: still get the same error. I tried to print the list _match_ but the result is empty

Comment: i get the solution, just need to add `launch{ verify(matchView).showMatchList(match) }`. thanks @kingston, you give me inspiration to find this solution, really" big thanks for you

Comment: the above comment from @FuadFadhilAzzar works for me also for this same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, I was able to execute tests independently but when I try to execute the entire file some of the tests fails. The solution added by OP in the comment worked for me. we have just had to put the `verify` function inside a `launch`

```
TestCoroutineScope().launch {
            verify(useCase, times(1)).getDetails()
        }
```

Comment: TestCoroutineScope is deprecated :
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-coroutine-scope/index.html


Please use TestScope 
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-scope/index.html#-33808464%2FExtensions%2F-1989735873